# mysqli_error is blank class to class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

When I got mysqli_query error the mysqli_error is blank or not showing any error message.

Example:

```
<?php
class xD
{
    function s()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','arena');
        
        return $conn;
    }
}

class xP extends xD
{   
    function a()
    {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM mytable";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($this->s(), $query) or die("Error in the consult..: " . mysqli_error($this->s()));
    }
}

$a = new xP();

$a->a();
?>
```

OUTPUT:

> Error in the consult..:

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a brand new database connection every time you need to reference the connection.

It would be better to pass the connection to your class and store it as a property:

```
class xD
{
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
}

class xP extends xD
{
    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        parent::__construct($conn);
    }

    function a()
    {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM mytable";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query) or die("Error in the consult..: " . mysqli_error($this->conn));
    }
}
```

Pass the connection in the constructor, and reference it from the property `$this->conn`:

```
// create the connection (maybe in a bootstrap?)
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','','','');

$a = new xP($conn);
$a->a();
```

Comment: It works. But there is no other way without $conn when calling the class. $a = new xP()?

Comment: It's better to pass dependencies to the object rather than have it create its own dependencies. Have a look into Dependency Injection, it makes it easier to unit test. You can create a factory that creates new xP objects and handles passing the connection so you don't have to keep writing `$a = new xP($conn)`, instead it could be something like `$a = $factory->createXp()`.